# What is the technique of this website?

Tags: animation, web

[This website](https://www.trizy.com.br/) shows an interesting technique where the figures are approaching the from sides as we scroll down and other animated effects.
Something that I found quite nice and light.
Would anyone know the name of the technique used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app is built using https://launchpad.animaapp.com/... you can actually get the css (it's not minified) and it's not pretty, seems that animaapp created their own animations. Here's a tool that could make your life easier https://github.com/jlmakes/scrollreveal It does not have many animation options like the solution proposed by @JABedford, but the plugin takes care to know when to reveal the object based on the scroll position.

Answer (score 1):

I am only viewing on mobile so not 100% if displaying as it should, however this looks primarily like “animate.css”

Demos of all the transitions can be found here:
https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/

Very simple to incorporate into any site.

Edit:

If you are not able to use the technique the above poster suggested it is perfectly viable to use animate.css and scrollreveal.js in unison. This will achieve you the exact same result as on the sample website.

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Comment: Your welcome. It’s a very neat little tool I have used several times.